# Can't run script on form submit or button click

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to `HTML`, `PHP` and `JavaScript`, so expect mistakes.
I've got the form working and sending contents via email in my `PHP` file. That works. I'm using the `Iframe` to keep people on page and that seems to work as intended.

I'm trying to get a bootstrap alert to appear once the form is submitted. So it's collapsed by default and I simply want it to appear once the form is submitted or the button pressed. I cannot figure it out for the life of me. The form will submit as expected but the script does not seems to run with the alert.

The script is within the HTML doc:

```
<script>
   function FormSubmit(){
       alert("The form was submitted");
       $('#AlertSuccess'.show('fade');
   }
</script>
<div id="AlertSuccess" class="alert alert-success collapse">
   <!--<a id="CloseAlert" href="#" class="close">&times;</a> -->
   <strong>Awesome</strong> We will contact you shortly
</div>
<div class="contact_form_container">
   <iframe name="keepitneat" style="display:none;">
   </iframe>
   <form id="contact_form" class="contact_form" action="/contact_send_btn.php" method="post" target="keepitneat" onsubmit="FormSubmit()">
      <input id="contact_form_name" name="name" class="input_field contact_form_name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required="required" data-error="Name is required.">
      <input id="contact_form_email" name="email"class="input_field contact_form_email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
      <input id="contact_form_number1" name="number1"class="input_field contact_form_number1" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" required="required" data-error="Phone number is required">
      <input id="contact_form_number2" name="number2"class="input_field contact_form_number2" type="text" placeholder="Landline Number">
      <button id="contact_send_btn" type="submit" onclick="FormSubmit()" class="contact_send_btn trans_200"  value="Submit">send</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

Please make me feel silly and point out the typo or logic mistake as I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: `$('#AlertSuccess'.show('fade');` <-- look at your statement.  You're missing a `)`.  Your browser console should be telling you you have a syntax error already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to hide the `#AlertSuccess` in default and on form submit, call the `show()` to display the message.

And you have forgot to close the bracket in `$('#AlertSuccess'.show('fade');`.
It should be

```
$('#AlertSuccess').show('fade');
```

```js
function FormSubmit(){
  $('#AlertSuccess').show('fade');
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="AlertSuccess" class="alert alert-success collapse hidden">
   <!--<a id="CloseAlert" href="#" class="close">&times;</a> -->
         <strong>Awesome</strong> We will contact you shortly
</div>
<div class="contact_form_container">
  <iframe name="keepitneat" style="display:none;"></iframe>
  <form id="contact_form" class="contact_form" action="/contact_send_btn.php" method="post" target="keepitneat" onsubmit="FormSubmit()">
      <input id="contact_form_name" name="name" class="input_field contact_form_name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required="required" data-error="Name is required.">
      <input id="contact_form_email" name="email"class="input_field contact_form_email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
       <input id="contact_form_number1" name="number1"class="input_field contact_form_number1" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" required="required" data-error="Phone number is required">
        <input id="contact_form_number2" name="number2"class="input_field contact_form_number2" type="text" placeholder="Landline Number">
        <button id="contact_send_btn" type="submit" onclick="FormSubmit()" class="contact_send_btn trans_200"  value="Submit">send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please clarify what you mean by 'hide it in default'? As in a seperate function to hide it?

Comment: you only need to show the message after form submission right? So, in default, use `display:none` to hide the message. After submission, the `.show()` function toggles the css and display the message

Answer (score 0):

The browser console (F12) should tell you about the syntax error in you javascript. You forgot the closing `)` in `$('#AlertSuccess'.show('fade');`.

```
$('#AlertSuccess').show('fade');
```